# Cannot convert titre of type class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Integer

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

I have this error;

> Cannot convert titre of type class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Integer

has anyone any idea ??

### File : search.xhtml

```
<p:dataTable var="item" value="#{annonceColocation}">

<p:column style="width:35%">
<f:facet name="header">Titre de mon annonce</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{item.titre}" />
</p:column>
</dataTable>
```

### File : flow.xml

```
<view-state id="mesAnnonces" view="mesAnnonces.xhtml">
    <on-render>
        <evaluate expression="userService.listMesAnnonce(annonceColocation, user.getEmail())"
            result="flowScope.annonceColocation" />
    </on-render>
</view-state>
```

### File : Service.java

```
 public List<AnnonceColocation> listMesAnnonce( AnnonceColocation annonce, String   email ) {
    UserEntity user = userDao.loadUserByEmail( email );
    return annonceDao.listeAnnonceColocation( user );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for  precious conseil, but i still have the same error

Comment: What does the bean look like?

Comment: Have you switched the field's type `titre` in the managed bean from `int` to `String` ?

Comment: `@Entity
@Table( name = "recherche" )
public class Recherche extends BaseEntity {

    private String            titre;
    private String            ville;
    private String            prix;
    private String            dureColocation;
    private String            description;`

Comment: in the first titre is String

Comment: any one know how to solve this error ??

Comment: Could you please edit your post and include all of your Recherche bean? :)

Comment: did anyone have a suggestion ??

Comment: i still have thé same error; but i don't know why ??